# Set annotative size to "NO" (use com ACAD 2014 Type Library)

Tags: c#, com, autocad

I use **com AutoCAD 2014 Type Library {D5C3CB6F-AA0A-4D45-B02D-CF2974EFD4BE}**. Is it possible set annotative size to "NO"?

```
AutoCAD.AcadApplication app = new AutoCAD.AcadApplication();
var docs = app.Documents;
var doc = docs.Open(dwg.FullName);
int blockCount = doc.Blocks.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < blockCount; ++i)
{
  AutoCAD.AcadBlock block = doc.Blocks.Item(i);
  int entityCount = block.Count;
  for (int j = entityCount - 1; j >= 0; --j)
  {
    AutoCAD.AcadEntity entity = block.Item(j);
    var obj = doc.HandleToObject(entity.Handle);
    /* I try set annotative here */
    obj./*???Annotative???*/ = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is available on the .NET API via AttributeDefinition.Annotation, but cannot see it on the COM Interop... is that what you seek?

Comment: yep. But **AttributeDefinition** not available in com :(. not only Annotation but annotative.

Comment: http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-4F448A62-A99E-4AB5-AE50-9EAAC0485283-htm.html